# App behavior via script different when display is asleep

Tags: macos, applescript, quicken

I have an AppleScript that runs every morning and evening. It tells Quicken (Mac) to update all accounts.

I have to do this because Fidelity has some private funds and the only way to get daily stock prices for them is to actually update the account.

My script runs perfectly via a shell script that is executed by launchd, provided that the display is not asleep. When the display is asleep, the script runs without error, but Quicken does not update.

Note: My Mac is set to prevent the computer from sleeping when the display is asleep.

AppleScript:

```
tell application "Quicken"
    reopen
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "U" using {command down, shift down}
    delay 1
    set visible of application process "Quicken" to false
end tell
```

Command in .sh script:

```
/usr/bin/osascript /xxx/bin/Stocks/scripts/QuickenUpdate.scpt 2>&1
```

Anyone know why it won't update when the display is asleep ?
Possible other causes for the behavior ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm - does GUI scripting even work if there is no display?

Comment: Interesting thought. I would think that apps should work even if there is a lack of a physical presence of a screen, either through missing hardware or sleeping.